# s3fs changing s3 permissions?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3fs

My developer believes that s3fs is changing my bucket's permissions.  Is this possible?   I want my bucket to be public, but it keeps reverting back to private.

Here's my fstab.

s3fs#production /mnt/production fuse use_cache=/tmp,use_rrs=1,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0

My developer mentioned the "-o default_acl (default="private")" option.  The documentation refers to "canned acl", but I don't understand what these are.

Comment: Just an FYI, you might want to accept some answers on your previous questions. http://serverfault.com/faq#howtoask explains things pretty well

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
s3fs#production /mnt/production fuse use_cache=/tmp,use_rrs=1,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000,default_acl=public-read 0 0
```

I have the same problem on dynamic files (bootstrap), although static files work well once the permissions are set. But the above solutions seem to work for others.

Comment: If that doesn't help, this might 
[persistent public permission for S3 mount](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094543/mount-s3-s3fs-on-ec2-with-dynamic-files-persistent-public-permission-solved/18094544#18094544)

Answer (score 0):

The deciding acl is actually per file/directory on an s3 bucket, unless s3 changed a lot since I last used it there is no such thing as an object having no acl and inheriting a default. So what really needs to be configured is what acl a new object is given initially. The default acl for your intentions would probably be "public-read" not "private"